# Percentile from bins of distributions

Tags: r

I need to find the "highest bin for 90% of samples".

I have a table like this:

```
my_table <- data.frame(matrix(c(122,68,2,0,30,0,0,0,5,79,23,9000), byrow=TRUE, ncol=4))
names(my_table) <- c("0-10","11-20","21-30","31-5000")
```

Where the bin-headers indicate minutes (time).

For the first row, 90% of samples are at intervals lower or equal to "11-20". I.e. 90% of samples have shorter time than 21 minutes.

For second row it is lower or equal to interval "0-10".

And for third row it is lower or equal to interval "31-5000".

I would like to add a column "90p-interval" where the above intervals are found automatically, resulting in the table like this:

```
my_table$Perc90 <-  c("11-20","0-10","31-5000")
```

My real table is thousands and thousands of rows long.

If someone can help I'm very grateful, and also thanks to everyone contributing to this fantastic site!

/Chris

Comment: What happens if there isn't > 90% in a single interval? Say, `my_table <- rbind(my_table, c(80, 10, 0, 10))`

Comment: If you look at the first row in the sample dataframe that is what happened.  The questioner finds the bin at which 90% has been achieved (including all before), the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apply(my_table, 1, function(x) names(x)[
               max( which( c(0,cumsum(x)) < 0.9*sum(x)))
                                      ])
# [1] "11-20"   "0-10"    "31-5000"
```

Comment: Yep, this is basically my solution given in the comment to "John"'s code.

Comment: Looking at the similar inequality equations I got to wondering about situations (obviously not time intervals like this case)  where sum(x) might be negative. Wondered if a solution involving ecdf()  might be needed.

Comment: DWin: I originally wondered about that--but what we have here is some pre-binned counts of data, not actual data values, so having negative counts is impossible.  If we started out with the actual data values, then the quantile() function and its relatives would do the job a lot faster and better.    In fact, I'd like to ask the OP: do you have your original time values?  If you do, you'd be a lot better off working with them than with this oddly lumped set of bins.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you want he 90% cutoff to be determined from your answer when it's not exact so I provided a response that gives you something that matches your example.  This makes sure the selected cutoff is at least 90%.

```
my_table$Perc90 <- apply(my_table, 1, function(x) {
    pct <- cumsum(x)/sum(x)
    return(names(x[pct >= 0.9][1]))
    }  )
```

Comment: Cute.  I found a slightly different alg. which looks like:`cumsum(x)/sum(x)/0.9 ->rowratio ` and then pick the first value of rowratio >= 1 . (Not checked)